# CSS3 Target multiple elements within multiple classes

Tags: css

I am trying to target all the heading elements within two classes (`'section2'` and `'section3'`) using this code:

```
.section2,.section3 h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    color:white;
}
```

But it is only targeting `section3`. Does anyone know why?

Edit:
This is my HTML:

```
    <section class="section2">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="section3">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.section3 h1 {
    color:white;
}
```

You're specifying `.section3 h1`, which is targeting the section3 h1 specifically, and is the only reason it works. To get it all working try this.

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
  color:inherit;
}
.section2, .section3  {
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.section2 h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6      ,.section3 h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
   color:white;
}
```